# Is 2 year IT degree with 4 year business degree enough?

Tags: job-search, education

I am about to graduate from a 2 year program with an associate degree in computer information technology(programming). I also have a bachelors degree in marketing. My question is, is this enough education to be able to not encounter big problems of having my resume thrown out by HR throughout my whole programming career due to not having a 4 year degree in CS? I'm ok with that happening at first, as long as things open up for me after getting a few years experience. I'm also ok if my resume gets thrown out some throughout my whole career, as long as there's still a lot of jobs that give me an interview.

I have researched this and the other posts I found on this site dealt with situations where someone had no degree, or someone who had a bachelors degree in a non CS field. I did not see any posts where someone had a bachelors in a non CS degree and an associate in programming, so I'm creating this post as it is quite a different situation than the posts I read.

Comment: I don't get your question. Why do you think your non-CS degree could be a deciding factor in "throwing out" your resume? If it really bothers you that much, and given that you do have a CS degree, just leave out the non-CS degree from your resume and be done with. Although I don't really see any reason why you should do so.

Comment: @Masked Man  Oh I don't think having the bachelors will be a problem. I'm hoping that having a two year degree in IT and a 4 year degree in marketing will be enough to not always get stopped by the requirement of having a 4 year degree in CS that I keep seeing on job applications.

Comment: That leaves me even more confused. If the 4 years CS degree is important enough for them to mention it in the job requirement, then how would a 2 year degree suffice? If they were okay with the 2 year degree, they would have said so. I still do not understand why your "other" degree should have any relevance in this question.

Comment: Masked Man-because one of the big reasons you will hear that employers require a degree is that they feel it proves dedication, which would apply with a non CS degree. Also, it seems like a valid question to wonder if a 2 year IT degree and a 4 year marketing degree will get me in the door.Thanks!

Comment: Too opinion-based and depends on company. Some may say "Let's interview him and see how it goes", others may say "Just a 2 years associates? Pass" and others may say "Our HR requires at least a 4 year degree in a relevant field. Pass."

Comment: @doc29 If I have a 5 year degree in hotel management, does that qualify? "A degree proves dedication" is one of the strangest reasons I have heard of. The most common reason though is that it makes their shortlisting job easier. As a recruiter, you have to pick 1 candidate and get 1000 applications, so what do you do? Narrow it down to about 20 applications. How do you do that in a "non discriminatory" way? Apply some reasonable filters, of course! One of them being, "does candidate have 4 year degree?" That cuts down the applicants to 350, wonderful! Next filter ...

Answer (score 1):

Some companies will have a policy (right or wrong) of *a* degree to be considered. 
You satisfy that.

Many programmers don't have a computer science degree.

Domain (marketing) knowledge is very valuable for a programmer working on marketing software.

It is not like back in C days where programming was difficult.  With modern languages and development environments like Visual Studio you don't need to know that much about raw computer science to put out valuable programs.

Comment: "You don't need to know that much about raw computer science" - what if your job is to write the development tools? Too over-generalized and doesn't adequately address OP's concerns.

Comment: @Brandin What if your job is not to write development tools?   Lots and lots of jobs writing business applications.   Lot of high paid statisticians and mathematicians doing data science without a computer science degree.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you would first target companies who are asking for degrees in CS and not specifying length. But nothing to stop you trying for the ones that do ask for 4 years, never heard of one myself.

Once you are in the industry, experience tends to carry more weight than a degree so once you actually have a job you can work on that angle. Many, especially older people (now in higher positions) may have entered the industry in the days when human resources were scarce and may not have any degree in CS at all. They and most senior techs value experience more highly.